# Google Webview and its use for simple login

Tags: android, android-webview

In light of the [webview debacle](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=google%20webview%20&gws_rd=ssl) our app has gotten some worried users complaining to our clients, but all we do with the webview is display things from our web service.  Here are the 2 ways we use it

1. Display the login page.  The login page would either go to our site or the user has the option to use google, yahoo, facebook, or microsoft live.  (javascript disabled)
2. Display fairly simple html pages (with javascript disabled), that come from the client.

Basically, our app is a front end for customers of our client to view data that we store for the client.  Is there really anything security wise that we should be concerned about?  Is there an alternate webview that can be used (sadly we have a 10% user base on Gingerbread)?

Comment: I am still googling and trying to figure out what exactly the point of concern. But possible solution I can think of is to use only trusted content i.e. load data from a local source or over HTTPS in your application. Google, Yahoo, Facebook and Microsoft Live use HTTPS. Need to handle your own login page. Will reply back in case I get any other solution.

Comment: we do use https currently for our own login page.

Comment: I was going through net and found [this](http://www.rafayhackingarticles.net/2014/10/a-tale-of-another-sop-bypass-in-android.html). Kindly ask concern team to test the POC and see if the issue exist while using HTTPS. If not, than you must be good to go and not to worry about. All the best. Ping me in case you need any further help or investigation requirement.